# Showing a dialog to user if not connected to internet for a week

Tags: android, timer

I am developing a POS app in which product list in the app is refreshed every 5 minutes. I am doing this with the help of timer and handlers. Now I want to add a functionality that if the user doesn't connect to the internet for a week, then I have to block the user from using the app anymore until he/she turns on the internet and the product list gets refreshed by showing a dialog with the said information.
So how can I achieve this functionality ? I thought of using notifications but since app is not connected then it will not receive notification too.

I have currently no idea how to achieve this so I can't post any code for this. I can only share the code which refreshes every 5 minutes in case of internet if that is related.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getProductList();
            getConfiguration();
        }
    }, 60000, 60000);
```

Comment: use alarm manager for this task. you should to store time in shared preference when the internet got disconnected. when user opens app and check if the internet is available or not. if not available Then check difference of time the last you stored and present time. If its greater than week then show the dialog or message to connect internet to user.

Comment: Ok I will try this

Comment: @HiteshSarsava will the alarm get cancelled after exiting the app ?

Comment: no it will not cancelled @Vivek Mishra